# How do I compile Traefik's source in macOS for contributing?

Tags: macos, traefik

Tried following the [contributing guide building steps](https://github.com/containous/traefik/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#building) but it says it only works for linux.

I've managed to build it using a macOS but got the following error when trying to run the 'traefik' file at the /dist folder

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

quickly, you can use `make crossbinary` or the [method 2](https://github.com/containous/traefik/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#method-2-using-go)